Authenticating a Teams License with our application
Our dev team is telling me that each one of our customers are going to have to login to their MSFT account and click a number of configurations before being able to enable their Teams account within our application.
I'm sure there is a way for us to build an interface where the client uses their existing Teams account name and password to authenticate with their Teams account.  That would enable their ability to use Teams as integrated with our solution.
We have integrated Teams in our Telehealth solution and want to allow our clients to login to their Teams account to connect Team with our front end services scheduler and virtual telehealth appointments.
Please help!?!
I've been told each client must configure their account by logging in to Entra and setting their company configuration keys which we then have to copy paste into our integration?
Shouldn't this all be done via an interface and APIs?
Most of our clients are NOT technical.

Are you trying to put your app -inside- Teams (i.e. as a tab inside a channel, or something like that)? Or is it a standalone app or website, and you want to give them the ability to "log in with your Teams / Microsoft account"? Both are possible but the answer I'd give is very different for each one.

Thank you Hilton.
It’s the second example. We have a platform and would like our clients to connect/bind their Teams license to allow them to use it within our platform.

ok great, got it - see answer below.

While it -is- possible to create an application in each tenant's Entra Id, it's definitely not required to do that. Instead, you can create an application once in your own Entra Id, and allow it as a "multi-tenant" application. After that, any client from any Entra Id instance can log in, they just have to consent to share their information with your app (it's a very similar experience to signing in to a new app on your phone with your Google or Apple Id). It's even possible for an administrator in that client tenant to consent on behalf of all of the tenant's users, so they won't even be prompted.
Microsoft provides a set of libraries for a whole range of languages that your development team can use to integrate this capability. See here for a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-overview
